# Exception propagation and context

Tags: c++11

What is the recommended practice to good context information in an exception? To illustrate here is an simplified example based on experienced.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/string_generator.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

class object
{
public:
  void parse(std::istream& is)
  {
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> eos;
    std::string buf(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(is), eos);

    std::vector<std::string> list;
    boost::split(list, buf, boost::is_any_of(","), boost::algorithm::token_compress_on);

    for (auto str : list)
    {
      auto id = boost::uuids::string_generator()(str);
    }
  }
};

void foo()
{
  {
    boost::filesystem::ifstream is("foo.txt");
    object obj;
    obj.parse(is);
  }

  {
    boost::filesystem::ifstream is("bar.txt");
    object obj;
    obj.parse(is);
  }
}

int main()
{
  try
  {
    foo();
  }
  catch (const std::exception& ex)
  {
    std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This example reads multiple uuids from two files. If one uuid is poorly formatted an exception is thrown and the output message is "invalid uuid string" which is correct.

In this simple and static example this is probably enough information to figure out the problem but in a more dynamic and complex situation it might not be enough. It would be nice to know which file that contained the invalid uuid and possibly which uuid that failed to parse. Obviously boost::uuid::string_generator cannot provide all that information. One approach would be to catch the original exception early and rethrow with more information but in this case I would need to do that twice to first get "uuid" value and then get "filename".

Appreciate any input on the matter.

Comment: This can be viewed as your test being a little too far removed from where the error is. If you tested inside `foo()`, which is where you read and thus where error can be detected at earliest, then it'd be a part of it to gather all info deemed needed (and rethrow what is most suitable). Then another layer of code would be nice, to wrap all that, the idea worked out in @atru's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you need more information for debugging, catch and then re-throw with a more informative error message.

```
void tryParse(string const &filename)
{
    boost::filesystem::ifstream is(filename);
    object obj;
    try{
        obj.parse(is);
    }
    catch(const std::exception& ex) {
        throw "Exception occurred whilst parsing " + filename + ex.what());
    }
}

void foo()
{
    vector<string> files = { "foo.txt", "bar.txt" };
    for(auto const& f : files )
    {
         tryParse(f);
    }
}
```

You could use std::optional instead, depending on which standard of c++ you are using.

This also depends on how you are logging your errors. If you have some sort of logging mechanism, you can log the exception message and filename when the exception occurs rather than propagating the information up.

Comment: Appreciate your response. The issue I have with this approach is that is clutters the code, requires more logic to implement\maintain and it introduces return code semantics which negates the purpose of using exceptions in the first place.

Comment: I guess it will depend on how you would like everything to flow. You can make a helper function that wraps around all throwing function calls. And the helper function should catch and output to stdout with a formatted error message. This will of course introduce more code, but it will be hopefully more usable and easier to maintain.

Comment: Of course, I'm not an expert in exceptions so it would be good if someone else offered some alternatives.

Comment: I also updated the code snippet so that there is no return code semantics. But yes, there will still be some catch re throw boiler plate code. But again, you can define a helper function to make it a bit more reusable.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate class that parses and handles related exceptions. I've no experience with boost and functionality in your example so mine doesn't use it - it still demonstrates the concept,

```
#include<iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <exception>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

// Parses a file, collects data if correct,
// if not throws an exception
class Parser
{
public:
    // Creates Parser object for parsing file file_name
    // verbose indicates whether more detailed exception message
    // should be printed
    Parser(const std::string file_name, const bool verbose):
            fname(file_name), print_ex_info(verbose) { }
    // Parsing wrapper that calls actual parsing function
    // and handles/prints exceptions
    void parse();
    // Retrieve parsed data
    std::vector<std::string> get_data() const { return data; }
private:
    std::vector<std::string> data;
    std::string fname = {};
    bool print_ex_info = true;
    // Actual parsing
    void parse_private(); 
};

void Parser::parse()
{
    try{
        parse_private();
    } catch(const std::exception& ex) {
        if (print_ex_info){
            std::cout << "File " << fname 
                      << " thrown an exception " 
                      << ex.what() << std::endl;
        }else{
            std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

// Throws if file contains an entry that 
// is not a positive integer 
// (for simple demonstration)
void Parser::parse_private()
{
    std::ifstream in(fname);
    std::string entry;
    while (in >> entry){
        if (entry.find_first_not_of("0123456789") != std::string::npos){
            throw std::runtime_error("Invalid entry " + entry + "\n");
        }else{
            data.push_back(entry);  
        }
    }
}

// Retrieves and uses data parsed from a file 
class Object
{
public:
    void parse(const std::string file_name, const bool verbose)
    {
        Parser file_parser(file_name, verbose);
        file_parser.parse();
        parsed_data = file_parser.get_data();
    }
    void print_parsed_data()
    { 
        for (const auto& entry : parsed_data)
            std::cout << entry << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::string> parsed_data;
};

int main()
{
    Object obj;
    bool verbose = true;

    // Correct input case
    std::cout << "No exception:\n";
    obj.parse("parser_no_ex.txt", verbose);
    obj.print_parsed_data();
    std::cout << "\n";

    // Invalid input, detailed exception info
    std::cout << "Exception - verbose version:\n";
    obj.parse("parser_invalid.txt", verbose);

    // Invalid input, reduced exception info
    std::cout << "Exception - minimal version:\n";
    verbose = false;
    obj.parse("parser_invalid.txt", verbose);

    return 0;
}
```

Here `Object` serves as an intermediate class that retrieves and uses parsed data. The parsed data is generated in the `Parser` object that also performs data checking and throws exceptions. This way the code that uses the data is not cluttered with parsing-related exception handling - this holds for both code that uses `Object` and functionality of `Object` itself.

For similar (cluttering, readability) reasons `Parser` has an extra code layer for parsing - the public function `parse()` has the exception handling code and makes the call to the actual, private parsing function that has no handling code but can throw.

In addition parsing has a `verbose` option that controls the amount of information the user wants to see after an exception is thrown. It's not a bad idea to be able to switch off more informative exceptions.

For reference these are the files used in this demonstration,

File with correct input (all positive integers) - `parser_no_ex.txt`:

```
123
456
900000
111
00
```

File with incorrect input - `parser_invalid.txt`:

```
123
456789
***Hello***
345
```